# How to bypass the authentication process of Ldap while accessing in-memory database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-ldap

I have developed a login page where a user can be a user from active directory(LDAP) or a local user from file based H2 database or a user from configuration file whose credentials are already stored ,For example Username - admin, Password - admin.

In the configuration file options are given to enable or disable LDAP, in-memory and H2 database authentication.

Let's assume all the 3 types of authentication are enabled and a local user from a H2 database logs-in, so according to the logic since all the 3 types of authentication are enabled a check is made in all 3 databases i.e. active directory,in-memory and H2 database if the user exists or not which should be avoided.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final Logger _LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

private ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Value("${ldap.auth.enabled}")
private boolean ldapAuthEnabled;

@Value("${database.auth.enabled}")
private boolean databaseAuthEnabled;

@Value("${inMemory.auth.enabled}")
private boolean imMemAuthEnabled;

@Value("${userrole.admin.username}")
private String adminUsername;

@Value("${userrole.admin.password}")
private String adminPassword;

@Value("${ldap.domain}")
private String ldapDomain;

@Value("${ldap.url}")
private String ldapUrl;

@PostConstruct
public void configValuesForApplication() {
    _LOG.info("Ldap Authentication {}", ldapAuthEnabled);
    _LOG.info("In Memory  Authentication {} ", imMemAuthEnabled);
    _LOG.info("Ldap Authentication {}", ldapAuthEnabled);
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/", "/reg",
                    "/js*//**//**",
                    "/css*//**//**",
                    "/img*//**//**",
                    "/webjars*//**//**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user*//**//**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/admin", "/h2_console/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    if (imMemAuthEnabled) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser(adminUsername).password(adminPassword).roles("ADMIN");
    }
    if (databaseAuthEnabled) {
        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role FROM USER where username=?")
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, 1 FROM USER where username=?")
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
    if (ldapAuthEnabled) {
        provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapDomain, ldapUrl);
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }
  }
}
```

login.properties file is as below

```
ldap.auth.enabled=true
inMemory.auth.enabled=true
database.auth.enabled=true

userrole.admin.username=admin
userrole.admin.password=admin
userrole.user.username=user
userrole.user.password=user

ldap.domain=foo.com
ldap.url=ldap://abcdef12.foo.com.:450/

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2_console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/h2/vehicledb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The question is how to avoid a check in LDAP and in-memory database if a user from H2 database logs-in and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own security provider

Example is available here:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers

Comment: "If you register multiple authentication providers it will only check against the first in the list." - it isn't true in Spring Security v5. You can see that ProviderManager#authenticate iterates over all AuthenticationProviders and the whole authentication process succeeds if auth in any provider succeed

Comment: Then this is new for spring 5, but as the question states he wants to completly ignore certain providers and dont want to iterate over all of them. This is still the best solution.

Comment: That's my point - ProviderManager iterates over all AuthenticationProviders and stop as soon as any of them succeed. So I would rephrase "it will only check against the first in the list" to "it will iterate and check one by one and stop as soon as any of them succeed" or something like that.

Comment: if you look at my post i have already edit the answer, this is an old answer to an old question. Why bring these things up to life?

Comment: Chill out, StackOverflow didn't display your edit when I was answering. I was looking for a solution to my problem and came over here just by coincidence. Found the issue, pointed out and that's all - I was always referring to the first version of your answer because it was misleading, so that was the only reason I have left a comment - to improve your post as StackOverflow creator intended comments to be used - "Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer."